# Why a disabled module throws error in magento compilation?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have a module "A" that depends on another module "B".

The dependency is defined in composer.json and in the `<sequence>` node. But this shouldn't be relevant.

However, I'm testing another branch/feature of the project that would remove the "B" module (that I am still developing).

So, **I disabled module "A"** to avoid errors with its dependencies.

✅ It's listed in the disabled modules. 
✅ I cleaned the cache, and also ran setup:up before compile.

However, even after cleaning `generated` folder, my `setup:di:compile` fails because of some Plugin class of (disabled) module "A" that relies on module "B" that no longer exist.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Module\B\Model\SomeClass' not
> found in /var/www/html/app/code/Module/A/Plugin/SomeClassPlugin.php:6

Is this a Magento bug, poor design, or I am missing something?

As far as I know, Magento should not compile classes in disabled modules. Am I right?

Comment: from where you disable the module? from the config.php?

Comment: Indirectly, yes. I used `bin/magento module:disable Module_A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know and understand from the compile command (`Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand`) it just simply scans the filessystem for components to register and include in the compilation. It doesn't actually check if the module is enabled or not.

So to truly exclude a module from compilation you'll need to either remove/rename registration.php from the module, or remove the module all together.

Comment: So poor design then! We can "disable" a module without physically removing it by renaming the registration file but can't disable it fully using the module:disable command. Go figure!! Thanks btw.

Comment: This is very poor design by magento.